# How to Put an image on top of the navbar

Tags: html, css

I need my image to be position: sticky but I need it on top of my navbar.
HTML5. this is for a school project I really need to get it done. please and thank you

```
       <div>
    <a href="index.html">
<img class="logo" src="./images/logo.png">
</a>
</div>
  <nav> <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
<a href="/pages/articles.html">Articles</a> 
<a href="/pages/contact.html">Contact</a>
<a href="/pages/sources.html">Sources</a></nav>
```

CSS

```
nav{ 
background-color: black; 
position: fixed; 
text-align: center; 
z-index: 10; 
top: 3%; 
left: 50% 
width: 100%; 
height:50px ; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
display: block;}

div{
transform: translate(-40%, 40%);
top: 3%;
z-index: 10;
overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: Do you want to sticky image, When scrolling ?

Answer (score 0):

try this and see if are what you want.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img class="logo" src="./images/logo.png">
        </a>
        <nav>
            <div>
                <img src="https://www.history.com/.image/ar_4:3%2Cc_fill%2Ccs_srgb%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto:good%2Cw_1200/MTU3ODc5MDg2NDMzNTEwNzI5/death-of-socrates.jpg"
                    alt="Your image" class="img">
            </div>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="/pages/articles.html">Articles</a>
            <a href="/pages/contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="/pages/sources.html">Sources</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 3%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: block;
}

div{
    height: auto;
}

.img {
    z-index: -1;
}
```